# PHP Script Parse Error unexpected '}' on line 11

Tags: php

I'm a new php programmer so its very hard for me to catch errors. It would be of much help for me if someone could explain the error

Whilst running my php in several online debuggers I continue to get the error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'exit' (T_EXIT) on line 11

However I do not believe this to be the case... could someone help me out?

```
    <?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';


    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php")
        exit()
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid ='$uid'"; 
        $result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultcheck < 1) {
            header("Location: ../index.php")
            exit()
        } else {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
                if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php")
                    exit()
                } elseif($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                    $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                    $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                    $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
                    echo "Correct";
                }
            }
        }
    }



} else { 
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error")
    exit()

}

 ?>
```

Comment: Semicolon.........................

Comment: Thank You I didnt know that required a ;

Comment: @KarlKanhai yessir... always use your punctuation. PHP does not like the lack of its semicolons.

Comment: I will keep that in mind

Comment: Please don't fix errors in your code which were involved in the question. It's confusing for people who are reading it after it's been answered.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I'm new to the platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing several semicolons

```
// you have
if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php")
    exit()

// you should have
if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php") ;
    exit() ;


// you have 
} else { 
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error")
    exit()

// you should have
} else { 
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error") ;
    exit() ;
```

Comment: To whomever voted this down - the OP changed their code after I posted. Their missing semicolons were valid at the time of my post (and three are still missing at the time of this comment).

Comment: Yes he is right ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ I will change my code back

Comment: Just add the missing semicolons